# Making use of awk on string

Tags: awk

I'm interested in listing in the terminal the lines from a csv file where the first character is 'A' . Is there a prompt way to do that?

Comment: Cross posted on U&L: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/173914/making-use-of-awk-on-strings

Answer (score 5):

Does it have to use awk? How about

`grep '^A' file`

ok, fine, awk:

`awk '/^A/' file`

(Should really try google for these type q's fisrt)

Comment: Xen2050: next time when you see a flag for a cross-post, don't answer and add a flag...

Comment: What? I answered before it was flagged (50 days ago now?), and my answer isn't even the same as that other muddled one. I don't remember adding a flag, didn't muru? I could've noticed afterwards...?

Comment: I've been up for 21 hours now....  Didn't see the date!  :/  I should go to bed!!!  ;-)  (Please forgive me!)

Comment: That's a long time without a nap... I avoid drinks like Red Bull for that reason :) and maybe they should color-code dates of posts somehow... happens to lots of users